# I want to transfer gridview record to another gridview

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to transfer gridview record to another gridview.
Actually I have placed a checkbox column in 1st gridview. Now what I want that when i select the checkbox of any row the related row transfer to 2nd gridview and when I deselect it that row it returns to its previous position in 1st gridview.`enter code here`
gridview 1:

        
        
        
        
        
        
        
            
            
            
            
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
     
gridview 2:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="Gridsales" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
         BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="I_AUTONO" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical"   
        onselectedindexchanged="Gridsales_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I_AUTONO" HeaderText="SNO" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I_INVOICENO" HeaderText="ITEM INVOICENO" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I_CODE" HeaderText="ITEM CODE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I_NAME" HeaderText="ITEM NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I_QTY" HeaderText="ITEM QTY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I_UNIT" HeaderText="ITEM UNIT" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I_RATE" HeaderText="ITEM RATE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="I_AMOUNT" HeaderText="ITEM AMOUNT" />
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: First of all is this a window or web app? Try to post your sample code.

Comment: Ok but what's the question here then?

Comment: @bogzy, did you noticed the added tags in question?

Comment: @Rahul you have 2 options to do this via client side or server side. From grid 1 add a function on row select then get the selected row from that data gridview then insert it to 2nd dridview by calling the gridview.row.add. I will try to post a sample code later.